# Failed to update model parameters

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, powerbi

When trying to connect PowerBI with Dynamics CRM Online, I am getting below error.  Please help if you have any suggestion to fix this issue.

> oops, something went wrong
>
> Failed to update model parameters
>
> Activity Id59a2a854-8e34-6636-0679-3d2e245d2241 Request
>   Id9b7fa606-324e-4ec8-495f-13f91d03bc54 Error Code400 TimeWed Mar 18
>   2015 21:24:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) Version11.0.9165.945
>   Cluster URIhttps://wabi-south-east-asia-redirect.analysis.windows.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another CRM online instance and it worked.  My colleagues believe that the issue is my original CRM instance was created on Cloud out of United States and Preview may not support connectivity to CRM out of USA.

Answer (score 0):

Best to submit errors like this through the "Contact Support" button on http://support.powerbi.com/?

Appreciate your using Power BI.

Lukasz P.

Power BI Team, Microsoft

Get started using Power BI APIs on the Power BI Developer Center - http://dev.powerbi.com. Keep up to date with the Power BI Developer Blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/.

Comment: I asked there but it takes time.  I am preparing for a demo and need help with setting up PowerBI with Dynamics CRM Online asap.  All online videos are showing simple seamless steps, but it is not working for me because of above.

Comment: If I use an existing worksheet created on my computer that has data source setup as Online Dynamics CRM, that is working.  But I need to demo PowerBI and CRM Online integration in Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

The URL appears to be case sensitive. https://[tenant].crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/

Comment: One thing to do when checking your url is to enter it into the browser and if works there it should work in the power bi ui as well.